# Difference tool for rasters

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator, differences

I am using QGIS 3.16.0 and I need to find the difference between two rasters that overlap in some areas (basically I need the areas that are not overlapped). First, I tried polygonizing the smaller raster so I extract the vector file obtained from the bigger raster, but the rasters are very big and polygonizing the smaller raster makes my computer to stop working since there are so many small polygons. I tried subtracting the smaller raster from the bigger one in raster calculator, but the result is the same as the second layer since the extent of both rasters are the same and both have only two values: 1 for where are trees and 0 for where there are not any tress. So using raster calculator will result in 0 for all areas.

How can I obtain the non overlapping areas of these two rasters?

Comment: I have no idea that you are familiar to procesing in Qgis or not. But in processing toolbar, which is in Menu-Processing, there is a processing tool called *Raster difference* under Saga-Raster Calculus. I think you can use it for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks @XiJin, that is what I was looking for.

Comment: @XiJin I think you should write an answer to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a processing tool called Raster Difference. You can find it under Processing-Toolbox-Saga-RasterCalculus.